# Retrieving Client Information from web service request

Tags: web-services, http-headers

If i have an applicataion requesting a service, is it possible for the web service to determine the name of the application or does this have to be sent within the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the UserAgent header of the HTTP request if the application sets it.

Answer (score 1):

This would have to be sent in the request, or in the headers, as the above post suggests.

There is no Internet standard as to what an "application" is, so there's certainly no standard for "application name".